# how to customise react native alert window size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wish to customise a size of react native alert window from its default view to cover entire width of iOS.
below is the code I have used to display alert box and I have added screenshot as well. [image]

```
 Alert.alert('oops','what to do ',[{text: 'agreed',onPress:()=>console.log('alert closed')}])
```

Two question

1. how can I edited this window, so that alert window cover entire
   width of screen .
2. Any idea would be highly appreciated if there is any way I can blur
   the background once alert box is displayed on screen

Comment: Alert cannot be customised. Use Modal instead: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.